# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type System.Windows.Controls.Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, wpf-controls

This is the error I'm getting - 'foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type System.Windows.Controls.Textbox because System.Windows.Controls.Textbox does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator.'

My code:

```
private void btnSendEmail_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
            message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            message.Body = txtBody.Text;
            foreach (string s in txtEmailAddresses)
            {
                message.To.Add(s);
            }

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
        }
```

There's a red squiggly underline on 'foreach' with that error. The textbox is supposed to be a multi-line textbox. With winForms this is easy. I could just go to the properties window and set the multi-line property to true, then it works fine, as long as the addresses the user enters are separated by a semi-colon. However, everything that takes 2 seconds in winforms needs to be a big problem in WPF, so I'm getting that error with the WPF textbox. Does anyone know why I'm getting that error and what to do about it? Here's my xaml too in case there's some property I'm missing that needs to be set on the textbox to make it multi-line or something.

```
<Label Content="Recipients:"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="26,10,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="Subject:"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="26,114,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtEmailAddresses"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="73"
                 Margin="26,36,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="278"
                 ToolTip="When providing multiple email addresses, separate them with a semi colon" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSubject"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Height="23"
                 Margin="81,117,0,0"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="223" />
```

Comment: `With winForms this is easy.` With winforms you'd have exactly the same problem, for exactly the same reason.  `Textbox` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<string>`.  You'd need to get the text and split it in exactly the same way.

Comment: This video says otherwise. http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=15&number=75

Comment: ...Did you actually watch the video? He uses `txtEmailAddresses.Text.Split(";")`

Comment: Ouch. Missed that part.

Comment: Please drink a glass of water and watch this video again. Though, video is not clear but in video he splits text with semicolon like @servy did in his/her answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your tooltip states:

> When providing multiple email addresses, separate them with a semi colon

it would seem the textbox has a bunch of semicolon delimited values.  You need to first get the text from the textbox, and then break that single string up into multiple strings before you have a sequence of things that you can `foreach`:

```
foreach (string s in txtEmailAddresses.Text.Split(';'))
{
    message.To.Add(s);
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this answer. It definitely got rid of that error without me having to create new methods. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Well yes... `txtEmailAddresses` is a `TextBox`. In neither Windows Forms *nor* WPF can you iterate over a `TextBox`. You need to get the text *from* that control. In Windows Forms you could use `TextBox.Lines` - but you still couldn't *just* iterate over the text box.

The documentation for [`TextBox.LineCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.linecount.aspx) gives some sample code for how to iterate over the lines in a WPF `TextBox`, although I'd modify it slightly to use a `List<string>`, possibly as an extension method:

```
private static List<string> GetLines(this TextBox textBox)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    // lineCount may be -1 if TextBox layout info is not up-to-date.
    int lineCount = textBox.LineCount;

    for (int line = 0; line < lineCount; line++)
    {
        lines.Add(textBox.GetLineText(line));
    }
    return lines;
}
```

(You could use an iterator block to return an `IEnumerable<string>` of course, but you'd need to make sure you didn't change the data in the control while you were iterating over it.)

Given your tooltip, however, what you *really* need is just:

```
string[] addresses = txtEmailAddresses.Text.Split(';');
```

(Basically, use the first code if you make it multi-line; use the second bit if you go with semicolon-separated addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can't iterate over a single `TextBox`, and a multiline `TextBox` seems to simply be a property set on the object rather than a subclass. I am not sure how this could be done other than reading the `Text` field of the `TextBox` object and splitting it into substrings based on semicolons and/or line breaks. Then you could iterate over the split collection and do what you're looking for.

Comment: The video you posted shows exactly what I and the others are suggesting. He uses the .Text field, and he calls .Split() on it. I am really confused.